# Why does $y = \frac{2A\sin(x\pi \ell)}{\pi^2 \ell (1-\ell) x^2}$ simplify to $y=c/x$ as $\ell$ approaches $0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, approximation

I am working on something using this equation, and I find something strange. I am manipulating $\ell$ here between $0$ and $1$. I note that as $\ell$ approaches zero ($\sim0.001$ or less) it becomes a graph of $y=c\frac{1}{x}$. I cannot understand why, or how $c$ would be calculated as a simplification/approximation of the equivalent full formula at this point.

The full equation is:
$$y = \frac{2A\sin(x\pi \ell)}{\pi^2 \ell (1-\ell) x^2}$$

As you can see as $\ell$ is close to $0$, this becomes equivalent to $y=c\frac{1}{x}$:

[image]

However, I don't know how this is happening, or what $c$ value would then reliably approximate the full equation at a certain value of $A$ (I just matched the curves visually here with an arbitrary constant).

Any help understanding the simplification and thus how $c$ could be calculated in terms of $A$ to roughly match in these circumstances?

Comment: $c=\frac{2A}{\pi(1-l)}$

Comment: If you take one more term in Taylor series $y=\frac{2 A}{\pi  x}\left( 1+l+O\left(l^2\right)  \right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall $\sin t \approx t$ for $t$ near $0$, so your equation can be approximated by
$$y = \frac{2A\sin(x\pi l)}{\pi^2 l (1-l) x^2} $$
$$\approx \frac{2Ax\pi l}{\pi^2 l (1-l) x^2}$$
$$=\frac{2A}{\pi  (1-l) x}$$
$$\approx \frac{2A}{\pi}\cdot \frac1x$$
(this last approximation because $1-l\approx 1$)

Answer (score 3):

For fixed $x \ne 0$,

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{l\to0}\left(\frac{2A}{\pi x}\cdot \frac1{1-l}\cdot\frac{\sin(x\pi l)}{\pi l x}\right)
&= \lim_{l\to0}\left(\frac{2A}{\pi x}\right) \cdot \lim_{l\to0}\left(\frac1{1-l}\right) \cdot \lim_{l\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(x\pi l)}{\pi l x}\right)\\
&= \frac{2A}{\pi x}\cdot 1 \cdot 1
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ is close to $0$, $$\frac{\sin x}x\approx 1$$ In your case, use $$\frac{\sin x\pi l}{x\pi l}=1$$
Therefore $$y=\frac{2A\sin(x\pi l)}{\pi^2 l(1-l)x^2}=\frac{2A}{\pi(1-l)x}\frac{\sin x\pi l}{x\pi l}\approx\frac{2A}{\pi(1-l)}\frac 1x$$
Note that for large $x$ values, or larger $l$, the function will oscillate around $0$.